# Changing junction object name

Tags: junction-object

I have an existing junction object that is named poorly and is causing a lot of confusion.

I wish to change the name of this object and move the changes to production.

Can you please let me know what are the things that I have to keep in mind when making this change?

I assume I will have to check all the Apex class/triggers/formula fields/validation fields etc for usage, deactivate them and change the name to refer to the new name accordingly.

Where can I find all the existing references to the existing junction object?

I also assume the code part of this must be tested for more than 75% to get deployed into production?

Anything I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the confusion exactly? in the related lists or while coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's confusing only for Internal Users then you can just update the Name of the SObject and you don't need to update code for it.

If you want to make the name more developer-friendly then you need to update API Name. In order to check where this SObject is referenced, you can just try to rename it and you'll get the error with the list of all references.

If you are using some IDE you can try to update everything in one step via API, since you can update references in APEX classes and SObject API Name itself in 1 API call. If not you can use a flow that you described - comment/disable, update, re-enable